# google.visualization.arrayToDataTable is not a function

Tags: html

Hi it's first time writing a post.
I am trying import google chart in javascipt. Some reason I keep on getting error of "google.visualization.arrayToDataTable is not a function".

I have imported *google api in my jsp*.

Comment: Dynamic loading should help https://developers.google.com/loader/#dynamic-loading

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code and make sure the API is included:

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Then the type of visualization you want to use must be loaded. For example:

```
<script>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['imagechart']});
</script>
```

Please provide some source next time you post a question :)